# Finding the control of a datetimepicker within a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a bootstrap datetimepicker within my grid view.  The problem is that I do not know how to cast like the textboxes.  Here is the markup code of my datetimepicker, also known as **txtStartDate**

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitDesc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date">
    <ItemTemplate>                             
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
            <input class="form-control" id="txtStartDate" runat="server" name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="color: green"> 
            </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

The problem I am having is that I am trying to find the control within my c# code and I do not know how to do it.  I have been looking online for ages and cant seem to find a direct answer.  Here is an example of my code

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv_Quals.Rows)
{
    TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)gvr.Cells[2].FindControl("txtUnit");
    txt1.Text = DSprog.Tables[0].Rows[rp]["UnitName"].ToString();

    TextBox txt2 = (TextBox)gvr.Cells[3].FindControl("txtUnitDesc");
    txt2.Text = DSprog.Tables[0].Rows[rp]["UnitDesc"].ToString();

    TextBox txt3 = (TextBox)gvr.Cells[4].FindControl("txtStartDate");
    txt3.Text = DSprog.Tables[0].Rows[rp]["StartDate"].ToString();

    TextBox txt4 = (TextBox)gvr.Cells[5].FindControl("txtFinishDate");
    txt4.Text = DSprog.Tables[0].Rows[rp]["FinishDate"].ToString();

    TextBox txt5 = (TextBox)gvr.Cells[6].FindControl("txtCompletionStatus");
    txt5.Text = DSprog.Tables[0].Rows[rp]["CompletionStatus"].ToString();

    TextBox txt6 = (TextBox)gvr.Cells[7].FindControl("txtStaffID");
    txt6.Text = DSprog.Tables[0].Rows[rp]["StaffID"].ToString();

    rp++;
}
```

I cant seem to find the right control.  Is there something I am missing or am I doing something wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to get something answered quickly, please format code, it will gain more attention

Comment: changed it to my best

Comment: Thanks, I took care of the rest of the editing.  This will bump it back to the top of the questions page as well.

Comment: Couple of things: your calendar input does not have runat="server", so your code will never pick up on it. Boostrap 4 breaks existing ASPNET templates - use v3.x. GridViews generate their own tables so will break RWD sites - use a ListView instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find a `TextBox` Control, but you are using a normal input with `runat=server`. But you need to look for `HtmlInputText`.

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv_Quals.Rows)
{
    HtmlInputText hit = row.FindControl("txtStartDate") as HtmlInputText;
    hit.Value = DSprog.Tables[0].Rows[rp]["StartDate"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: tried that, I'm getting a nullreferenceexception on the second line.  Sorry for the late reply

Comment: fixed that, the calendar isn't displaying in the grid view but the textbox is there so it is a step in the right direction

Comment: The code should work just fine. Are you sure the `DSprog.Tables[0]` is not null?

Comment: Nah, the calendar textbox along with the bootstrap components are showing its just when I click onto the textbox the calendar does not display